# Calculating major axis of an ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

How do I calculate the length of the major axis of an [ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)? I have the eccentricity and the length of the semi-major axis.

Comment: You multiply the length of the semi-major axis by 2. You don't need the eccentricity. The semi-major axis is half the major axis by definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Eccentricity) points out, the eccentricity $\epsilon$ of an ellipse obeys the equation $$\epsilon=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2}$$ where $a$ and $b$ are respectively the semi-major and semi-minor axes of the ellipse.

Comment: Um, the question asked for major axis from semimajor axis--- the answer is "multiply by 2".

Comment: @Ron: sounds like an answer to me...

Answer (score 8):

Multiply the semi-major axis by 2, and that's the major axis.

Answer (score 0):

The semi-minor axis $b$ of an ellipse can be found by the equation
$${b}=\sqrt{{a}^2(1-\epsilon^2)}$$

where $a$ and $\epsilon$ are respectively the semi-major axis and eccentricity of the ellipse.